# How to compare keys in array with files on server?

Tags: php, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, automation

I have 2 questions about a PHP file with an array like so:

`$test = array('test1.txt' => '<random>',
               'test2.txt' => '<random>',
               'test3.txt' => '<random>',
               'test4.txt' => '<random>',
               'test5.txt' => '<random>');`

I also have files on my server like so:

```
    /home/test1.txt
    /home/test2.txt
    /home/test3.txt
    /home/test4.txt
    /home/test5.txt
```

How would I go by checking that every file that is defined in the array also exists in the folder /home/ and that all files in /home/ are defined in the array?

Q2) Is there a way to automatically grab the file names in /home/*.txt and automatically insert them into an empty array like:

```
    $test = array('' => '<random>',
                   '' => '<random>',
                   '' => '<random>',
                   '' => '<random>',
                   '' => '<random>');
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/foreach http://php.net/file_exists http://php.net/glob

Answer (score 1):

Q1) You can check if a file is on your server from an array of path with file_exists function.

```
foreach ($test as $str_filename=> $random) {
    if (file_exists('/home/' . $str_filename) === false) {
        echo 'A file is missing on server';
    }
}
```

You can grab .txt file with glob function like this.

```
foreach (glob('/home/*') as $str_filename) {
    if (array_key_exists($str_filename, $test) === false) {
        echo 'A file is missing on array';
    }
}
```

Q2) If random is the content from the file, you can grab it with file_get_contents function.

```
$test = [];
foreach (glob('/home/*.txt') as $str_filename) {
    $test[$str_filename] = file_get_contents('/home/' . $str_filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Q1) The file itself is a script, how would it be possible to run it as a separate php file without adding it to the script (i.e. so i can define the scriptname array_key_exists searches in). Same for Q2 but <random> isn't the content from the file, just random inputs i will be adding in manually.

Comment: If by run it you mean include this file in order to user function or PHP class  you have to use [include](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php) or  [require](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.require.php)  function based on need.

If you need to execute it from a server shell you have to use the function  [exec](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php) or  [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.shell-exec.php)  function.

Be careful with exec and shell_exec function because you may have not the right to execute them on your server.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach ($test as $fileName => $value) {
    if(file_exists("/home/{$fileName}")) {
        //exists
    } else {
        //Does not exist.
    }
}
```